# I deleted .htaccess but its effetcts remain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm getting started with making few redirect with .htaccess but I just made something wrong.
I was trying to make a redirect where when I write http://www.mydomain.com/it/about the browser jump to http://www.mydomain.com/it/about.php but I wrote something wrong!
I can't remember exacly what I wrote (I took some code over the Internet several times) but the problem now is that I've deleted the .htaccess but when I try to access to http://www.mydomain.com/it/about.php the browser is redirected to http://www.mydomain.com/it/about.
How can this happen???? There is not any .htaccess into the server!!!!!!

Comment: If it was 301 redirect then modern browsers DO CACHE such redirects. Therefore try cleaning browser cache and restart it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a 301-Redirect (`[R=301]`), the Browser will cache the redirect. Try an other browser or delete your cache

Comment: That's right man! Using Chrome everything works, thanks! I'll call the exorcist for the server that I don't need him anymore :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's gone? `.htaccess` files are hidden for security.

Try uploading an empty `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

disable the rewrite module by typing "a2dismod rewrite" in terminal and re enable it. this will remove effects of .htaccess file.